# Tracing the authenticated() method in the default laravel auth functionality

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5.1

I am currently using this method to provide a flash message to a user after a user logged in. This is using the default auth functionality of `laravel(5.1)`.

Somebody suggested my to use this method in my `AuthController` to override the default one.

```
    public function authenticated(Request $request, User $user ) {
        // Succes flash message
        alert()->success('Succesvol ingelogd', 'Welkom');

        return redirect()->intended( $this->redirectPath() );
    }
```

The only problem is that I can not exactly figure out where this method comes from. Once a user logs in, the user will post his data to the **postLogin** method on the **AuthenticatesUsers** trait. If the auth attempt is successful this method calls the **handleUserWasAuthenticated**.

This method calls the the authenticated method like so:

```
    protected function handleUserWasAuthenticated(Request $request, $throttles)
    {
        if ($throttles) {
            $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);
        }

        if (method_exists($this, 'authenticated')) {
            return $this->authenticated($request, Auth::user());
        }

        return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
    }
```

I can not figure out where the `authenticated()` method is coming from though. Can somebody help me with figuring this out. I would like to understand more about this code so I don't have to constantly ask others for help with it.

Comment: I dont think you will find it by default as you can see it uses method_exist() to check if you added one which somebody suggested to you. So it means if you added this method authenticated() then return to this method (with alert msgs and any custom code you need) and not just the default behavior which is return redirect()->intended(); only

Comment: Wow that makes sense. Didn't think of that. I was still in the mindset of adding method to override the default auth methods.

Comment: Cool. Glad I could help.